# archivo php que guarde la data enviada por POST y al mismo tiempo reenvíe el indice para seguir usándolo en otro formulario

Tags: php

Muy buenas..
Quisiera saber si es posible y si lo es como seria.
Tengo un formulario, este es enviado por POST a otro archivo .php que es el encargado de guardar la data del formulario es decir lo almacena en el motor de DB mysql, lo que deseo es que este archivo que hace la tarea de guardar la data que en mysql no solamente guarde la data del formulario, si no que al mismo tiempo me reenvié el indice con el que se viene trabajando en le formulario para seguir usándolo en otro formulario, son varios formulario los cuales dependen de un indice y se va pasando con siguiente mientras se guardan, espero ser mas claro según me lo solicita.

Este es el archivo que les comento que guarda la data del formulario en mysql

```
<?php 
require("../controlador/conect.php");
$conexion = new mysqli($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra, $db_nombre);
$arrResult=array();
if(!$conexion){
    $arrResult['error'] = "No lograste conectarte ! VERIFICA";
}else{
    $conexion->set_charset("utf8");

    $orden_h       =(!empty($_POST['orden_hm']))     ?   $_POST['orden_hm']         : NULL;                
    $cod_a         =(!empty($_POST['cod_asesore'])) ?   $_POST['cod_asesore']       : NULL;
    $fecha_i       =(!empty($_POST['datepickers'])) ?   $_POST['datepickers']       : NULL;
    $fecha_p       =(!empty($_POST['datepicker']))     ?   $_POST['datepicker']     : NULL;
    $orden_a       =(!empty($_POST['o_servicio']))    ?   $_POST['o_servicio']      : NULL;
    $tipo_activida =(!empty($_POST['tipo_actividades'])) ?   $_POST['tipo_actividades'] : NULL;
    $programas     =(!empty($_POST['programa']))     ?   $_POST['programa']         : NULL;
    $actividad     =(!empty($_POST['d_actividad']))    ?   $_POST['d_actividad']    : NULL;
    $observ        =(!empty($_POST['observar']))     ?   $_POST['observar']         : NULL;
    $arls          =(!empty($_POST['a_arl']))  ?   $_POST['a_arl']                  : NULL;
    $tel_arl       =(!empty($_POST['telef']))  ?   $_POST['telef']                  : NULL;
    $correo        =(!empty($_POST['email_asesor']))  ?   $_POST['email_asesor']    : NULL;
    $ciu           =(!empty($_POST['ciudad']))  ?   $_POST['ciudad']                : NULL;
    $asignada      =(!empty($_POST['u_asignada']))  ?   $_POST['u_asignada']        : NULL;
    $unida         =(!empty($_POST['unidad']))  ?   $_POST['unidad']                : NULL;
    $ejecutada     =(!empty($_POST['u_ejecutada']))  ?   $_POST['u_ejecutada']      : NULL;
    $unidad        =(!empty($_POST['v_unidad']))  ?   $_POST['v_unidad']            : NULL;
    $rubros        =(!empty($_POST['o_rubros']))  ?   $_POST['o_rubros']            : NULL;
    $asignado      =(!empty($_POST['s_asignado']))  ?   $_POST['s_asignado']        : NULL;

    $strSQL =  "INSERT INTO servicio (
                                            orden_serv_hm,
                                            cod_asesores,
                                            fecha_genera,
                                            fecha_solitud_ord,
                                            orden_serv_arl,
                                            tipo_actividad,
                                            fecha_programa,
                                            detalle_actividad,
                                            observa,
                                            arl,
                                            tel_arl,
                                            correo_arl, 
                                            ciudad,
                                            unidad_asignada,
                                            unidades,
                                            unidad_ejecutada,
                                            valor_unidad,
                                            rubros_asignados,
                                            salon_asignado

                                     )

                                VALUES   (  ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?  )";


    $stmt = $conexion->prepare($strSQL);



    $stmt->bind_param("issssssssssssssssss",$orden_h,$cod_a,$fecha_i,$fecha_p,$orden_a,$tipo_activida,$programas,$actividad,$observ,$arls,$tel_arl,$correo,$ciu,$asignada,$unida,$ejecutada,$unidad,$rubros,$asignado);      


    if(!$stmt->execute()){
        $arrResult['error'] = "El Ingreso de factura que desea realizar no es permitido. ".$conexion->error;


    }else{

        $totalInsert=$stmt->affected_rows;  
        $mensaje=($totalInsert > 0) ? "Se ha insertado correctamente" : "No fue posible la inserción. Error: ".$stmt->error;  
        $arrResult['mensaje'] = $mensaje;

        echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Datos de Facturación Ingresados Correctamente'); window.location='probar.php'; </script>";



        echo "<form class=\"form\" method=\"POST\" action=\"probar.php\"  >"; 
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"orden_hm\" id=\"orden_hm\" value=".$unico.">";

    }
}
```

?>

este Luego de cumplir su función de guardar la data del formulario me reenviaría el indice para en le siguiente formulario seguir hasta terminar de llenar los 3 formulario.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tu pregunta no es clara: *lo que deseo es que **este** no solamente guarde la data*  ¿quién es *este*?  y esto tampoco es claro: *si no que al mismo tiempo me reenvié el **indice** para seguir usándolo en otro formulario*  ¿qué índice?  ¿que lo reenvíe a dónde? ¿Hablas de una inserción en la base de datos o algo así? Además conviene que indiques lo que has intentado hasta ahora y dónde tienes el fallo. Gracias.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya logré editar mi pregunta, Espero ser mas claro.

Comment: Ok, ahora se entiende mejor. Sin embargo la lógica que usas no queda clara. O sea envías el formulario una primera vez con un dato (lo que tu llamas *índice*) ¿cierto? Se ejecuta una acción y ¿ **quieres recuperar de nuevo ese mismo *`indice`***  para otra acción o lo que quieres recuperar es el nuevo `ID` del elemento que se ha insertado en la base de datos (puesto que veo que tienes un `INSERT`)?. Otra cosa, ¿qué ocurre luego de ese primer envío, a dónde retorna el programa? Y dinos si estás usando Ajax, porque esa sería la clave para resolver tu problema de forma óptima.

Comment: @A.Cedano pues en este no estoy usando Ajax, la idea es que como el formulario que inicia con un ID este no se haga tan extenso en una sola pagina pues es largo, por el contrario pasa al siguiente formulario por medio del ID  hasta lograr llenar todos los dato, p[ero en cada uno de ellos debe guardar y pasar al siguiente. la finalidad del programa llenar los 3 o 4 formularios y así culminarlos.

Comment: No entiendo mucho lo que dices. O sea, no llego a entender qué ocurre luego del primer paso, dónde tendrías ese segundo formulario, etc. No obstante, se pueden hacer cosas como tener  los otros formularios ocultos e irlos mostrando de forma progresiva (o generarlos de forma dinámica, según el caso). Así el código queda organizado y es práctico. Desde una misma página vas llenando y enviando los diferentes formularios, los cuales no se cargarán todos de golpe, sino uno después de otro. Y para comunicar con el servidor usar Ajax, así no hay que recargar la página y tienes siempre el dato a mano.

Comment: @A.Cedano Esta linea 

echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Datos de Facturación Ingresados Correctamente'); window.location='probar.php'; </script>";

Es la encargada de realizar la re dirección luego de haber guardado la data del formulario como ya lo expuse en el código, será posible agregarle el id a esta linea y así mismo poderlo tomar en el siguiente formulario para seguir llenando los demás formularios.

Comment: Sí, todo es posible. Pero la forma en que estás planteando la cuestión no es la más idónea. Como ya te comenté anteriormente, en vez de complicarte con redirecciones a otras páginas puedes ir cargando los formularios de forma progresiva en la misma página. Te voy a poner un ejemplo muy sencillo...

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza:

```
$unico = $conexion->insert_id
```

para retornar el "**id**" o "**indice**" del ultimo registro insertado.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a equipos como este uno puede compartir y salir de dudas para avanzar en proyectos, quiero compartir la manera como le dí solución al caso, realmente no se si es la mas practica, pero intenté y me resulto.
En el archivo .php que se encarga de hacer el insert luego del if le coloqué un poco de JavaScript, este :

var pagina="orden_segunda_etapa.php?orden_h=" 

function redireccionar() 
{ 
location.href=pagina 
} 
setTimeout ("redireccionar()", 1000);

y en el siguiente formulario que era donde quería seguir avanzando con la carga de información, el cual tenia que recibir el ID o indice le coloqué:

$orden = $_REQUEST['orden_h'];

?>
y pues de esa manera controlo ese ID o indice, de la manera como muy amablemente me sugeria Carlos Gonzales el detalle es que si el usuario por x o y no terminó ese registro o ingreso seguiría con el siguiente consecutivo o ID o Indice el cual haría parte del siguiente.
Espero haber sido claro.
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo completo de formularios dependendientes.

En este caso para que se pueda probar y ver los resultados, he usado llamadas a la API de Github de forma secuencial:

1. Se trae una lista de usuarios (Formulario 1)
2. Se traen los repositorios de ese usuario (Formulario 2)
3. Se trae la primera página de la lista de repositorios posteriores al repositorio seleccionado (Formulario 3)

Aquí hay varias llamadas a llamada Ajax a diferentes puntos de la API de Github (en tu caso sería hacia tu servidor). La lógica está montada en base en un elemento `mObjects` que contiene dentro las diferentes url a las que hay que llamar, los elementos que siguen, si es el último elemento, qué claves de la respuesta de la API debe usar para encontrar los valores, etc. Eso permite reutilizar el código y no llenarlo de `if then else` de `switch ... case` y cosas parecidas. Mediante un objeto puedes organizar una lógica mucho más compleja, como llenar formularios con diferentes tipos de campos, etc.

He puesto comentarios en el código para que se comprenda mejor. Esto es sólo una muestra de como se puede desde una misma página lanzar diferentes peticiones y actualizar los datos de la página sin moverse de ella.

Si por ejemplo no quieres mostrar los tres formularios de golpe, también hay técnicas para mostrar ocultar elementos de forma dinámica. Lo he hecho así para no complicar demasiado el asunto.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Puedes probar el código pulsando en el botón azul **`Ejecutar`**.

```js
/*
   Objeto que representa los diferentes elementos 
   sus valores, la url de llamada, etc
   Lo ponemos fuera de function porque vamos a referirnos a él
   en diversas partes del script
*/
var mObjects = {
  "users": {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users",
    "fieldV": "login",
    "fieldT": "login",
    "nextPart": "repos",
    "isLast": false
  },
  "repos": {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/*/repos",
    "fieldV": "name",
    "fieldT": "id",
    "nextPart": "since",
    "isLast": false
  },
  "since": {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repositories?since=*&page=1",
    "fieldV": "name",
    "fieldT": "id",
    "nextPart": "",
    "isLast": true
  }
};

$(function() {
  /* 
      Configuración inicial
      El punto de entrada es users
      por eso signamos aquí su url
  */
  var dataPart = 'users';
  var thisUrl = 'https://api.github.com/users';

  /*
    Esta llamada carga los datos del 1er formulario
  */
  sendAjax(dataPart, thisUrl);

  /*
      Este evento ocurre únicamente cuando cambie
      el select del 1er formulario
      Los select dependientes son agrupados por una clase
      aquí los vaciamos cuando cambie el 1er select
      Esto mismo se puede hacer con un formulario completo
      o sea limpiar todos sus elementos
  */
  var allDependent = $("select.dependent");
  $('#users').on('change', function() {
    $.each(allDependent, function(i, el) {
      $(el).find('option').not(':first').remove();
    });

  });


});

/*
    Esta función sirve para llenar cada select
    con los nuevos datos que se le pasen de forma dinámica
*/
function getNewData() {
  var thisUser = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  var thisPart = this.dataset.nextPart;
  var thisObject = mObjects[thisPart];
  /* 
     Cambiamos el * por el nombre de usuario
  */
  var thisUrl = thisObject.url.replace("*", thisUser);
  sendAjax(thisPart, thisUrl);
}

function sendAjax(dataPart, thisUrl) {
  if (dataPart in mObjects) {
    var thisObject = mObjects[dataPart];
    var request =
      $.ajax({
        url: thisUrl,
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json"
      });

    request.done(function(data) {
      var thisForm = document.getElementById(`form-${dataPart}`);
      var thisSelect = document.getElementById(dataPart);
      thisSelect.disabled = false;

      /*
          Aquí se limpia el select actual, menos el principal 
      */
      if (dataPart !== "users") {
        $(thisSelect).find('option').not(':first').remove();
      }

      thisSelect.dataset.nextPart = thisObject.nextPart;

      /*
          Cuando sea el último formulario 
          no agregamos evento on chage
          porque no hay más datos dinámicos que traer
      */
      if (!mObjects[dataPart].isLast) {
        thisSelect.onchange = getNewData;
      }
      $.each(data, function(k, v) {
        thisSelect.options[thisSelect.options.length] = new Option(v[thisObject.fieldV], v[thisObject.fieldT]);
      });
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      alert("Error en la petición: " + textStatus);
    });

  }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="allForms">

  <div id="div-users">
    <h4>Form. 1: users</h4>
    <form id="form-users">
      <select id="users">
        <option value="-1">--Seleccione User--</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="div-repos">
    <h4>Form. 2: repos</h4>
    <form id="form-repos">
      <select class="dependent" id="repos" disabled>
        <option value="-1">--Seleccione Repo--</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="div-since">
    <h4>Form. 3: since</h4>
    <form id="form-since">
      <select class="dependent" id="since" disabled>
        <option value="-1">--Seleccione since--</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
  
</div>
```